# Boot Camp Assistant cannot be used. This Mac does not support Boot Camp

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Air and every time I try to download bootcamp it always says the same thing.'Boot Camp Assistant cannot be used. This Mac does not support Boot Camp.'  can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Is it an M1 Mac?

Only Intel Macs can use Boot Camp. See [Apple KB - Boot Camp Support](https://support.apple.com/boot-camp)
There are ways to run Windows on M1 Macs, but you need Windows for ARM processors. There are many articles about this online, here's one - [MacHow2 - How to run Windows on M1 Macs](https://machow2.com/windows-on-m1-mac/)